# Exception in soap method call in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, web-services, exception, soap, wsdl

I am trying to call the following web service 
http://iskynettrack.skynetwwe.info/TrackingService/TrackingService_v1.asmx
but I am getting in response:

> Exception in ValidateConsignor(consignorUsername, consignorPassword,
>   consignorAccount, stationCode) Method: Procedure or function
>   'ValidateConsignorLoginDetails' expects parameter '@UID', which was
>   not supplied. Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [GetSkyBillTrackResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
>   [GetSkyBillTrackResult] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [errorMessage] =>
>   Exception in ValidateConsignor(consignorUsername, consignorPassword,
>   consignorAccount, stationCode) Method: Procedure or function
>   'ValidateConsignorLoginDetails' expects parameter '@UID', which was
>   not supplied. ) ) ) ) Array ( [soap:Body] => Array (
>   [GetSkyBillTrackResponse] => Array ( [GetSkyBillTrackResult] => Array
>   ( [errorMessage] => Exception in ValidateConsignor(consignorUsername,
>   consignorPassword, consignorAccount, stationCode) Method: Procedure or
>   function 'ValidateConsignorLoginDetails' expects parameter '@UID',
>   which was not supplied. ) ) ) )

I am supplying everything correctly here is my code.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://iskynettrack.skynetwwe.info    /TrackingService/TrackingService_v1.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1));

$datatrack=array('consignorUsername,'=>"R1803362", 
'consignorPassword'=> "R1803362",
        'consignorAccount'=> "R1803362",
              'stationCode'=> "DHX",
              'isRef'=>"0",
               'shipmentNumber'=> "088800202392");

$crshipment=$client->GetSkyBillTrack($datatrack);

$strresp=$client->__getLastResponse() . "\n";
```